# Redux toolkit running multiple queries even with preventing it

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using redux toolkit RTK with multiple hooks inside one single component, but the issue is that they are running together even I'm using the params `skip` which I dont want it in this case, here is my code:

```
const { data, isFetching } = useGetTestsQuery(filters, {
    pollingInterval: 5000
});

const {
    data: testsByStatus,
    isFetching: fetchDataByStatus
} = useGetTestsByStatusQuery(filters, {
    pollingInterval: 5000,
    skip: data
});
return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data || testsByStatus} />;
```

in network tab I can see that both requests are running in same time, can I prevent eg. `useGetTestsByStatusQuery` from fetching while there are some data in `useGetTestsQuery` or vice-versa ?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are skipping if there is data and not skipping if there is no data.

You probably want to do

```js
useGetTestsByStatusQuery(filters, {
    pollingInterval: 5000,
    skip: !data
});
```